# sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 not working

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, aircrack-ng

I am new in Linux. Just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I installed some updates so I can use `aircrack-ng`. When I write `mixa@mixa-Lenovo-G780:~$ sudo airmon-ng start eth1`, I get:

```
Found 4 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID Name
890 avahi-daemon
891 avahi-daemon
897 NetworkManager
911 dhclient


Interface   Chipset     Driver


mixa@mixa-Lenovo-G780:~$
```

And on other Linux (Kali Linux), I had same problem. I had nothing under interface, chipset, and driver.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

`airmon-ng` is used to put **wireless** interfaces into monitor mode, so that you can capture packets (the equivalent of "promiscuous mode" on Ethernet cards).

The command that you are trying `airmon-ng start eth1` is trying to turn on monitor mode for `eth1`, which is an Ethernet interface, not your wireless interface, so it will not work. You need to use `airmon-ng` for your wireless interface. Your wireless interface is usually `wlan0`.

To find out the exact name of your wireless interface, you can execute the command `iwconfig`, which should show you something like this:

```
alaa@aa-lu:~$ iwconfig

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Alaa"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.472 GHz  Access Point: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:514   Missed beacon:0

vmnet8    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

vmnet1    no wireless extensions.
```

From the output, you can see that `wlan0` is a wireless interface.

So, the command to turn on monitor mode for `wlan0` is `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0`.

If however, you don't have a wireless interface (which is probably the case, looking at your output), then I need to ask the question of *why do you want to run `airmon-ng` when you don't have a wireless card*?

If you're installing this Ubuntu (or Kali) as a virtual machine, then `aircrack-ng` will never work, because a virtual machine will always see an Ethernet card, not the wireless card. The only way you can make a virtual machine see a wireless card is by using a wireless USB adapter, such as this one:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to have an wireless interface like `wlan0` to use `airmon-ng` and as I can see from your output, you don't have it. I deduced this because the output for these fields `Interface   Chipset     Driver` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

airodump-ng mon0 doesnt even worked for me too!

Try inserting the previous command as "arimon-ng start wlp3so" instead of "airmon-ng start wlan0"

because wlan0 works for lan network while wlp3s0 works for wireless network

then run command "airodump-ng mon0". it will surely work for u too

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please do not post [duplicate answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6546/how-to-handle-duplicate-answers) on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.